# How to intercept field accesses (without getter/setter) using Bytebuddy

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I am trying to use bytebuddy to intercept `getfield` and `putfield` accesses. I have read the rather comprehensive documentation on the site, but from what I can understand, it covers adding getters and setters to fields, rather than intercepting field accesses.

Here is basically what I am trying to do:

```
...
obj.prop = value;
x = obj.prop;
...
```

That in both these cases, I am trying to have some method called (or some bytecode inserted) before/after the field access. I was thinking of using `Advice` to do it, but I am unable to find a way to have it for something other than methods.

Edit:

I am using a Java Agent to do it.
I had an idea of adding a `dup` to duplicate the object reference followed by the call to a static method I defined to intercept the access (I only care about the object being referred to, not the field).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a new component that is still under development but that is already exposed with a basic API. It is called `MemberSubstitution` and allows you to replace a method call or field access with another execution.

This component does however rely on replacing the code that executes an instruction. Field access is non-virtual, therefore it is not possible to create any proxy class that would intercept a virtual access. Instead, you have to redefine any existing class that reads or writes the field, for example by using a Java agent.

As for your more specific question: At the moment, there is only a 1-to-1 substitution possible. I have not yet had the time to include a mechanism for adjusting the stack and local variable sizes. Also, you would also have to *dup* objects lower down on the stack if the field is non-static. The problem is not trivial so to say but I hope to offer such functionality some day.

At the moment you can however replace the field access with a static method call. Possibly, you can execute the original field operation from this method.

Comment: Thank you!
I am indeed using a java agent to transform classes, I have edited the question to include that information as well now.
I think that is definitely possible by using `AsmVisitorWrapper`, but I was wondering if I can use bytebuddy's API some way instead.

Comment: I extended my answer.